# When do I must use the spread operator in useReducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've noticed that in many `useReducer` examples, the spread operator is used in the reducer like this:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment1':
      return { ...state, count1: state.count1 + 1 };
    case 'decrement1':
      return { ...state, count1: state.count1 - 1 };
    case 'increment2':
      return { ...state, count2: state.count2 + 1 };
    case 'decrement2':
      return { ...state, count2: state.count2 - 1 };
    default:
      throw new Error('Unexpected action');
  }
};
```

However in many of my practices, I removed `...state` and had no issues at all. I understand that `...state` is used to preserve the state of the remaining states, but would a reducer preserve those states already so the `...state` is not needed?

Can someone give me some examples where `...state` is a must and causes issues when removed with `useReducer` hook? Thanks in advance!

Comment: State is an object. If you are overwriting every key in state, you will technically return a complete object and as such not need the spread operator (until you add another key to your object and don't update that in a reducer event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a reducer function alone would ***not*** preserve existing state, you should ***always*** be in the habit shallow copy existing state. It will help you avoid a class of state update bugs.

A single example I can think of when spreading the existing state may ***not*** be necessary is in the case where it isn't an object.

Ex: a "count" state

```
const reducer = (state = 0, action) => {
  // logic to increment/decrement/reset state
};
```

Ex: a single "status" state

```
const reducer = (state = "LOADING", action) => {
  // logic to update status state
};
```

Spreading the existing state is a ***must*** for any state object with multiple properties since a ***new*** state object is returned each time, in order to preserve all the existing state properties that are not being updated.

## Edit 1

> Can you give an example when NO shallow copying causing state update bugs?

```
const initialState = {
  data: [],
  loading: false,
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case LOAD_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    
    case LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.data,
        loading: false
      };

    case LOAD_DATA_FAILURE:
      return {
        loading: false,
        error: action.error,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

As can been seen in this example, upon a data load failure the reducer neglects to copy the existing state into the new state object.

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

...

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch({ type: LOAD_DATA });
  // logic to fetch and have loading failure
}, []);

return (
  <>
    ...
    {state.data.map(...) // <-- throws error state.data undefined after failure
    ...
  </>
);
```

Any selector or UI logic that assumes `state.data` *always* exists or is always an array will fail with error. The initial render will work since `state.data` is an empty array and can be mapped, but upon a loading error `state.data` is removed from state.

Comment: Thanks, can you give an example when NO shallow copying causing state update bugs?

Comment: @thinkvantagedu An example could be something similar this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64983049/how-to-make-state-iterable-and-resolve-unhandled-rejection-typeerror-state-s/) I answered just yesterday. I'll distill it into a simpler example in my answer.